# Parse Through JSON response - React Native

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, react-native, parsing

Sorry for the newb question but I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have a returned JSON string from Firebase of:

```
{ 
   "user":{ 
      "uid":"kjsahdfkpa9asjdf",
      "displayName":null,
      "photoURL":null,
      "email":"test12@test.com",
      "emailVerified":false,
      "phoneNumber":null,
      "isAnonymous":false,
      "tenantId":null,
      "providerData":[  ],
      "apiKey":"asjdf;lkajd;lkfj;laV0",
      "appName":"[DEFAULT]",
      "authDomain":"test.firebaseapp.com",
      "stsTokenManager":{ 
         "apiKey":"Aalskfdeeee9V0",
         "refreshToken":"Aalskdf;lakdfjdjbA",
         "accessToken":"eyJaslkdjf;akldfhg",
         "expirationTime":q48r894q7qq4
      },
      "redirectEventId":null,
      "lastLoginAt":"q8437508234",
      "createdAt":"34534522"
   },
   "credential":null,
   "additionalUserInfo":{ 
      "providerId":"password",
      "isNewUser":true
   },
   "operationType":"signIn"
}
```

Why can I not simply pull out the apiKey value by doing:

```
const response = await config.loginViaRedux(user); //this is what returns the JSON string
const apiKey = response[0].user.stsTokenManager.apiKey;
```

Comment: Because `response` is an object and not an array. Try doing  `response.user.stsTokenManager.apiKey`

Comment: @PrerakSola when I try that I get an error `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_response.user.stsTokenManager.apiKey')`. Do I have to do anything with JSON.parse() or stringify it before I pull out the values?

Comment: Why is there an `_` before `response`? Also, `"expirationTime":q48r894q7qq4` is not valid in JSON. The value should be inside `""`.

Comment: @PrerakSola i just removed the actual data with fake data for security purposes. And I am not sure why there is a _ before response as I do not have that in my code. The response is coming back from an API callout....

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the response as array but it's an object. Ive read the above comments, so i think what you should do is wait for the response object to load. So please try this approach and see if it helps:

```
const response = await config.loginViaRedux(user);
let apiKey = "";
if(response && response.user && response.user.stsTokenManager){
apiKey = response.user.stsTokenManager.apiKey;
}

console.log(apiKey,'apikey')
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not work. it can't read response at all unless I stringily it. When I try to pull out any values (even after I can see it has loaded via the stringified console.log()) I get null values back